# How to create a generic mapping on NHibernate?

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I'm having a trouble with class mapping here. I have four tables:

- Fix
- Request
- Control
- Message

`Request` has foreign keys to the tables `Fix` and `Message`, while `Control` has a foreign key to `Request`. The basic mapping works OK, but I don't want to map the foreign key between `Request` and `Message` directly with the type of `Message`, since we won't use this class - we make all our inserts and selects through various views that accecss this Message table.
The view to be used will depend on a value stored in the `Fix` table, for example, `Message101` is a view over `Message` (we don't use all fields and there are other business specific reasons why we don't want to use the table `Message`).

With the specified scenario, the basic idea is to have a mapping like this:

```
public class Request: Entity
{
    public virtual short Number { get; set; }      
    public virtual Fix Fix { get; set; }
    public virtual IMessage Message { get; set; }
}
```

being `IMessage` an interface implemented by all the `Message` classes. I tried using generics in the `Request` class, but to no avail. Maybe using `MappingOverride` can help?

Thanks

**Edit:**

In order to use `Any` I've put the value used to find the object type on the `Request` table, so my override looks like:

```
    public override void OverrideMapping(IClassMapper<Request> __m)
    {
        __m.Any(x => x.Envio, typeof(long), m =>
            {
                m.IdType<long>();
                m.MetaType<short>();
                m.MetaValue(101, typeof(Message101));

                m.Columns(id =>
                {
                    id.Name("MessageId");
                    id.NotNullable(true);
                }, classRef =>
                {
                    classRef.Name("MessageType");
                    classRef.NotNullable(true);
                });

                m.Access(Accessor.Property);
                m.Cascade(Cascade.None);                   

            }
        );
    }
```

But I keep receiving the `not-null property references a null or transient value` error. Any ideas?

Comment: Just clarifying - you want nHibernate to dynamically instantiate the Message property using one of a selection of classes, and the business logic for selecting this class type will depend upon another value in the related table called "Fix".

Comment: Can you tell which `IMessage` type to instantiate just by looking at the Fix foreign key, or do you have to actually join to Fix and look at another column?  If you can tell just by looking at the foreign key, then the `<any>` mapping would work.

Comment: I can tell just by the foreign key, but I have no idea how this ´<any>´ works. I'm mapping it by code, forgot to say.

Comment: do you create an instance of Message in the constructor? Or the unsaved value is special and has to be mapped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, I had to put the reference of the discriminator field on `Request`, which enabled me to use the `Any` mapping from NHibernate. The issues I described in my edit of the question are unrelated to the question itself in my opinion, therefore, the solution presented by [Daniel Schilling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/221708/daniel-schilling) solved my problem. About the `Any` mapping, a description of how it works can be found [here](http://notherdev.blogspot.com.br/2012/02/mapping-by-code-any.html).